# Visual Studio error: not defined identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am facing an issue while trying to execute the following C++ code (with microsoft visual studio Enterprise 2015 on Windows 7 x64):

```
//Test704.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

//#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "704IO.h"
#include "Test704.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
  #define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CWinApp theApp;  // The one and only application object

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

using namespace std;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[], TCHAR *envp[])
{
int     nRetCode(0);
HMODULE hModule(::GetModuleHandle(NULL));
short   valueRead;

  if (hModule != NULL)
  {
    // Initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
      // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
      _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
      nRetCode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      while(true)
      {
        valueRead = PortRead(1, 780, -1);
        _tprintf(_T("Value Read = %i\n"), valueRead);
        Sleep(1000);  // Sleep for 1s so we can see the value on the screen
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
    _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failed\n"));
    nRetCode = 1;
  }

  return nRetCode;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

And I have the 16 following errors:

```
Identifier "CWinApp" not defined (line 13)
Identifier "TCHAR" not defined (line 20)
Identifier "TCHAR" not defined (line 20)
Identifier "HMODULE" not defined (line 23)
The global scope doesn't have "GetModuleHandle" (line 23)
Identifier "NULL" not defined (23)
Identifier "AfxWinInit" not defined (29)
The global scope doesn't have "GetCommandLine" (line 29)
Identifier "_tprintf" not defined (line 32)
Identifier "_T" not defined (line 32)
Identifier "_tprintf" not defined (line 40)
Identifier "_T" not defined (line 40)
Identifier "Sleep" not defined (line 41)
Identifier "_tprintf" not defined (line 48)
Identifier "_T" not defined (line 48)
TRK0005: Failed to localize "CL.exe": The specified file cannot be found (line 1)
```

However I have already executed this code with another version of visual studio (2012) on a windows 7 x32 computer and it worked perfectly. I suspect the error to be about my configuration... do you have any idea?

Comment: I would assume this to be important `//#include "StdAfx.h"`. Why commented out?

Comment: Yes, but I commented it because I have even more errors with StdAfx.h

Comment: @ManaV Typically, those not-defined identifiers are defined in `Windows.h`, which would be included in `StdAfx.h` by default. So, as your question now stands, your fix would be to uncomment this line: `//#include "StdAfx.h"`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidzius Yes, that was one of my hypothesis, however, windows.h is not defined in StdAfx.h, and when I try to, I have an error "Impossible to open the source file "Windows.h". Same error when I try to include "StdIO.h", "TChar.h" and "IOStream"

Comment: @ManaV If `#Include <Windows.h>` fails for you, there is something wrong with your VS installation. And, please tell me, that you aren't trying to include Windows.h with quotation marks (`"..."`) instead of: `<...>`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidzius No, I am not